# Sed to match the first of the recurring character

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My regex for displaying everthing after "(" :

```
 echo "apples (orange) (plum)" | sed -re 's/^.+\(//'
```

Output :   `plum)`

Expected output :`orange) (plum)`

How can I catch the first occuring character instead of the last ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "apples (orange) (plum)" | sed -re 's/^[^(]+\(//'
```

. matches any character, therefore sed watches the last bracket in the line.
Therefore `.` mathes `(` and  `^[^(]+\(` mathes `apples (orange) (`.
So you need to use `[^(]*` to not match any `(` at all as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Can't. .* and .+ are always greedy. There are other ways to accomplish this though.

Delete all leading non-`(`'s

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*(//' <<<'apples (orange) (plum)'
orange) (plum)
```

Or almost equivalent and not really an improvement would be saving the second part using a group.

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*(\(.*\)$/\1/' <<<'apples (orange) (plum)'
orange) (plum)
```